# Check if a cell has a single quote in the beginning

Tags: ms-office, office-js

In Excel, in a cell we could add a single quote before a formula (e.g., `'=3+4`), to let the formula not evaluate. And in the formula bar, we could see the single quote.

[image]

Is there a JavaScript API to check if a cell has such a single quote?

We tried `formulasLocal` and `values`, but they all returned the formulas and formulas without the single quote.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no JavaScript API to check if a cell has such a single quote. We track Office Add-in feature requests on our [Microsoft 365 Developer Platform Ideas Forum](https://aka.ms/m365dev-suggestions), please add your request there. Feature requests on are considered when we go through our planning process.

Thanks,
Microsoft 365 Developer Platform Team